# Compare two string on their shift

Tags: java, string, shift

First, the code:

```
String account1= "0000180000";
String account2= "0000000180";
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

for (; i < account1.length() -1; i++ ) {
   char test1 = account1.charAt(i);
   while (test1 != '0') {
      System.out.println(i);
      break;
   }
}

for (; j < account2.length() -1; j++) {
   char test2 = account2.charAt(j);
   while (test2 != '0') {
      System.out.println(j);
      break;
   }
}

if (i > j) {
   int res = i-j;
   System.out.println(res);
} else {
   int res = j-i;
   System.out.println(res);
}
```

I get 0, instead of 3, as the result of the shift .

What am I doing wrong in the code? Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mean shift, or rotate?

Comment: Thanks John, with i & j can I find out the index, where the shift happens.

Comment: @hamadakarim Could you please accept the best answer you got?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should replace your while with an if.
The break within the while means: exit from the current loop, which is the while itself, but you want to exit from the for I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be an `if` not a `while`

```
while (test1 != '0'){
    System.out.println(i);
    break;
}
```

Also this `for (; i < account1.length() -1; i++ )` should probably be `for (; i < account1.length(); i++ )`

Answer (score 1):

The `break` only breaks you out of the `while` loop, not the `for`.

I think you probably meant to put:

```
if (test1 != '0'){
    System.out.println(i);
    break;
}
```

and

```
if (test2 != '0'){
    System.out.println(j);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the many helper methods from the runtime?

```
String account1= "0000180000";
String account2= "0000000180";

String pattern = account1.replaceAll("^0+", "").replaceAll("0+$", "");
int pos = account2.indexOf( pattern ); // TODO Check this for != -1 to make sure there is a match
int res = Math.abs( account1.indexOf( pattern ) - pos );
```